# Photon mass Infrared divergence regulization in the one-loop electron self-energy in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, regularization, self-energy

So basically I'm trying to calculate the one-loop mass and field strength counterterms from the electron's self-energy in QED using Pauli-Villars regularization (i.e. some heavy particle of mass $\Lambda$) and on-shell subtraction. I know there are various schemes but I'm struggling at a specific integral. I'm following the book by Schwartz (p. 333 eq. 18.47) and one obtains after integration over the loop momentum a final integration over a Feynman parameter for the $e^2$ correction:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\Sigma_2(\not p)=\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\int_0^1dx(x\not p-2m_P)\ln\left(\frac{x\Lambda^2}{(1-x)(m_P^2-p^2x)+xm_{\gamma}^2}\right)
\end{equation}
where a Photon mass was added for regularization of the IR divergence arising via the renormalization condition 
$-\frac{d}{d\not p}\Sigma_2(\not p)\vert_{\not p=m_P}=\delta_2$ at $x\to1$. Now simply differentiating the equation gives:
\begin{equation}
\delta_2=-\frac{d}{d\not p}\Sigma_2(\not p)\vert_{\not p=m_P}=-\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\int_0^1dx\quad 
\left[x\left\{\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}+\frac{(1-x)^2}{x}\right)\right\}-\frac{2x(1-x)(2-x)}{x\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}+(x-1)^2}\right]
\end{equation}
and one sees that the photon mass regulates the divergence in the second term as desired. Now the first term can be integrated to give (in the $m_{\gamma}^2\to0$ limit):
\begin{equation}
\delta_2=-\frac{d}{d\not p}\Sigma_2(\not p)\vert_{\not p=m_P}=\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\left[
-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2}\right)-\frac{5}{4}-\int_0^1dx\quad\frac{2x(1-x)(2-x)}{x\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}+(x-1)^2}\right]
\end{equation}
and I'm a bit lost on the second term. My method was to cut the integral, thus separate the $x\to1$ region and then to expand in $m_{\gamma}^2$. For this I simply used Maple and we get
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1dx\quad\frac{2x(1-x)(2-x)}{x\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}+(x-1)^2} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left[\int_0^{1-\epsilon}dx+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1dx\right]\frac{2x(1-x)(2-x)}{x\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}+(x-1)^2}=\ln\left(\frac{m_{\gamma}^2}{m_P^2}\right)+1+\mathcal{O}(m_{\gamma})
\end{equation}
which does agree with the result in Schwartz. 
**Now what I'm actually asking is how do I get this kind of result without having to use a tool like Maple.** 
In the book, the step between the equation for $\Sigma_2(\not p)$ and the result in $\delta_2$ was simply stated as "keeping only the leading terms in $m_{\gamma}$". How can I "see" this kind of result? I'm quite open to any dirty tricks as more often than not, this whole game is rather questionable. But I simply don't see how this is an obvious "Taylor and ignore higher terms" kind of situation. I could accept that what I've done was indeed the way to go, but how is that obvious? If someone has an idea so I can avoid spending quite some time on calculations like this, I'd be glad for any suggestions.